# Magento2 count # of customers purchasing for first time

Tags: magento2, database

I have a magento 2.2.5 based website and what I want to do is for the current month count the number of people who were logged in as a customer and made a purchase for the first time (first time buyers).

The query I am using below does not seem to return the correct # of orders.
it is giving me some numbers but they seem way to low compared to what I see in the admin panel.

```
  SELECT num_orders AS OrderCount, count(customer_id) as CustomerCount
         FROM (
                SELECT COUNT(1) AS num_orders, sfo.customer_id
                FROM sales_order_grid AS sfo
                WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-28'  AND sfo.customer_id > 0    
                GROUP BY sfo.customer_id
              ) AS T
 GROUP BY num_orders ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has [quite a number of predefined order states](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-status.html). Is it possible your `IN` statement makes your query too narrow? Perhaps you could try a `NOT IN` statement that weeds out the orders you don't want to count (for example, cancelled orders).

Comment: thank you @kookaburra I edited my query as sown in my original post above. I removed the status but now what happens is the query shows me a total of 120 in the customercount column but when i go into Magento admin sales order page and filter all orders in this date range selecting each of the customer groups I get a total of 133 so my query seems to be short by 13 ?

Comment: Set your maximum created_at value to '2019-01-28 23:59:59'. Right now, by not specifying the timestamp, you're asking your database for all orders created up to 2019-01-28 00:00:00, which is probably where the discrepancy lies.